# how does maven profile id use var?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

profile is:
i use ${artifactId} as profile id.

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>${artifactId}</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>distribution.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Running maven in shell:
`mvn -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true -f pom.xml -Pabc_test clean install`

Then I catch an error:

> [WARNING] The requested profile "abc_test" could not be activated because it does not exist.
>   Finish

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to define all your profiles in pom.xml.

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
                    <activation>
                        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                    </activation>
                    <properties>
                        <war.name>dev</war.name>
                    </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
                    <id>prod</id>
                    <properties>
                        <war.name>prod</war.name>
                    </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Here the profile names are `dev` and `prod`. You can use `${war.name}` as the variable modified by the profile.

Comment: this method can run. but i want't id is a var, such as '<id>${artifactId}</id>'